# Longtext data to PHP Array

Tags: php, mysql, json, longtext

I inserted the array data in `MySql` table by encoding to `JSON` using `json_encode($arrayData)`, but in `longtext` data type, not in `JSON` data type.

So I am not able to do `json_decode($Db_Data_Stored_In_Longtext)` for getting back the `$arrayData` while fetching the same from database. Any clue?

Comment: Perhaps it is simply that you forgot to add the `JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY` flag to [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode)? An [actual example of what you do](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. What goes in, what goes out? What errors?

Comment: On the face of it this should work. Post some sample data and the `CREATE TABLE` statement and the code that you're using.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, Thanks for your, time, its working!

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode($Db_Data_Stored_In_Longtext,TRUE,512,JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY);`

For more info visit [json_decode() PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)